# How do you escape apostrophe in single quoted string in bash?

Tags: bash, shell-script, string, escape-characters

I don't understand how bash evaluates escaping of apostrophe characters in single quoted strings.

Here is an example:

```
$ echo ''\''Hello World'\'''
'Hello World' # works

$ echo '\'Hello World\''
 > # expects you to continue input
```

I've tried looking for explanations to this but couldn't get anything. What is bash doing here?

Comment: `echo \''Hello World'\'`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In single quotes, no escaping is possible. There is no way how to include a single quote into single quotes. See *Quoting* in [man bash](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash).

You can, however, end a single quoted string and enter an apostrophe either in double quotes or escaped by a backslash.

```
echo 'string'"'"
echo 'string'\'
```

Comment: You're right. The trick is in that line 'A single quote may not occur betweeen single quotes even when preceded by a backslash' So it probably splits it into different parts.

Comment: @Colin As soon as a single quote is inside of two other single quotes (but backslashed), the quoted quote isn't a real quote anymore. It is just a char with no special pairing characteristics.

Comment: @zero2cx: Not true: `echo '\''`

Comment: @zero2cx: I would say "outside" instead of "inside".

Comment: @choroba not "totally" true, in bash you can do ``echo $'\'hello world\''``

Comment: While this answer is technically correct, it’s not useful as there are ways to achieve this, see [kenorb’s answer](https://superuser.com/a/883858/84807), for example.

Answer (score 13):

In addition to POSIX-supported single- and double-quoting, `bash` supplies an additional type of quoting to allow a small class of escaped characters (including a single quote) in a quoted string:

```
$ echo $'\'Hello World\''
'Hello World'
```

See the QUOTING section in the `bash` man page, near the end of the section. (Search for "ANSI C".)

Comment: It's great! Thx

Answer (score 10):

Simple example of escaping quotes in shell:

```
$ echo 'abc'\''abc'
abc'abc
$ echo "abc"\""abc"
abc"abc
```

It's done by closing already opened one (`'`), placing escaped one (`\'`) to print, then opening another one (`'`).

Alternatively:

```
$ echo 'abc'"'"'abc'
abc'abc
$ echo "abc"'"'"abc"
abc"abc
```

It's done by finishing already opened one (`'`), placing quote in another quote (`"'"`), then opening another one (`'`).

What you did (`'\'Hello World\''`), is:

1. Opened 1st apostrophe:`'`.
2. Closed right after it `\'`, so the string becomes: `'\'`.
3. `Hello World` is not quotes.
4. Placed standalone apostrophe (`\'`) without opening it.
5. Last apostrophe (`'`) is opening string, but there is no closing one which is expected.

So the correct example would be:

```
$ echo \'Hello World\'
'Hello World'
```

Related: [How to escape single-quotes within single-quoted strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1250079/55075)

Answer (score 4):

To explain what is happening with your escaped apostrophes, we'll examine your second example (also see [single quotes](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/abs-guide.html#QUOTING), or [strong quotes](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting)):

```
$ echo '\'Hello World\''
>     # expects you to continue input
```

Here, you've left the quotation hanging, as you've stated. Now trim the end and change it to:

```
                     v                                v           v
$ echo '\'Hello World     # Echo two strings: '\' and 'Hello World'.
\Hello World         ^
```

The "Hello World" sub-string wasn't quoted here, but it behaved *as if* it was strong quoted. Using your example again, trim the end differently this time:

```
                     vv                                    v (plain apostrophe)
$ echo '\'Hello World\'   # Will echo: '\' and 'Hello World''
\Hello World'        ^^   # Note that the trailing ' char is backslash escaped.
```

The "Hello World" sub-string again behaves as if it were strong quoted, with only the added apostrophe (escaped, so no longer a single quote) at the end.

When another single quote is added to the end (your original example) the string is left hanging and waiting for a close-quote.