# How do I output this line to a remote file?

Tags: bash, escape-characters

I'm using a bash shell and trying to figure out the right way to write the following:

```
ssh mysuer@remotehost 'echo "update user set url = \'localhost\' where url = \'mydomain.com\';" >> /tmp/db.sql'
```

So far the above is not working.

After hitting enter the following line is a `>` as if it is expecting for me to close an open quote somewhere.  What do I need to do so that this

```
update user set url = 'localhost' where url = 'mydomain.com';
```

is output to the remote file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Escaping apostrophe in single quotes string in bash](http://superuser.com/questions/481797/escaping-apostrophe-in-single-quotes-string-in-bash)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Single quotes can't be escaped, but you can end the existing one, print apostrophe (`\'`) and open the new one.

Here is the right syntax:

```
ssh user@host 'echo "update user set url = '\''localhost'\'' where url = '\''mydomain.com'\'';" >> /tmp/db.sql'
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work if you remove the backslashes from the single quotes inside the mysql statement:

```
ssh mysuer@remotehost 'echo "update user set url = 'localhost' where url = 'mydomain.com';" >> /tmp/db.sql'
```

Comment: That doesn't work.  Instead, what is otuput to the remote file is "update user set url = localhost where url = mydomain.com;".  Notice the single quotes are missing around the keywords where I want them.

Comment: ok, try changing the single quotes inside the mysql statement to escaped double quotes.

Comment: here's another way: `ssh mysuer@remotehost 'echo "update user set url = '"'localhost'"' where url = '"'mydomain.com'"';"'`